# Sonarqube server not reachable

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am running simple java based web application using maven as building tool.
but when I build the project in jenkins I am getting below error.`

```
[ERROR] SonarQube server [localhost:9000] can not be reached 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project webapp: 
Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server:
Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
```

Comment: [ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Comment: ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project webapp: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging

Comment: There's all sorts of information that you haven't provided that would be useful for diagnosing this.

Did you install SonarQube somewhere, or are you expecting to use an enterprise installation of it?